# Export weight of best model in <kerasmodel>.fit() with Keras to variable

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

```
best_save = ModelCheckpoint('best_'+parameters['flag']+'_autoencoder.hdf5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only= True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')

autoencod.fit(x=datatrain, y = datatrain, validation_data = (datatest,datatest), epochs = parameters['epoch'], shuffle=True, batch_size=parameters['batchSize'], callbacks=[best_save])

last_model = autoencod
autoencod.save('last_'+parameters['flag']+'_autoencoder.hdf5')
```

How can I get the weight of the best model in a variable (without save in .hdf5)? I need to get "best_model" like "last_model" but I don't know how. :(
Ps: the type of "last_model" is tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.functional